# General method to solve absolute functions

Tags: functions

I am just wondering, is there a general method to solve equalities and inequalities involving absolute valued functions?

Case i) $|x\pm k|= |x \pm l| + c$

Case ii) $|x \pm k| \ge |x \pm l| +c$

I would appreciate some detailed solution to solving the general cases I am confused  with above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For either case we can assume that $k, l \in \mathbb{R} $ so the problem becomes:
$$|x+k| = |x+l| + c$$
There are 2 possible cases for each of the absolute values, giving 4 possible solutions for $x$:
$$x+k = x+l + c \Rightarrow x \in \mathbb{R}, k = l+c$$
$$x+k = -(x+l) + c \Rightarrow x = \frac{c-k-l}{2} $$
$$-(x+k) = x+l + c \Rightarrow x = \frac{-c-k-l}{2} $$
$$-(x+k) = -(x+l) + c \Rightarrow x \in \mathbb{R},k = l-c $$

Comment: But how do we know which is the real answer cane we express it in some inequality?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean. All of these answers are the real answer - there are 4 different solutions.